# Django page & category names showing as objects

Tags: python-3.4, django-1.7

This code is showing page and category names as objects and not by their respective title. Its supposed to show the names and its showing page objects and category objects instead for all the titles

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

import django
django.setup()

from rango.models import Category, Page


def populate():
    python_cat = add_cat('Python')

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
        title="Official Python Tutorial",
        url="http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/")

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
        title="How to Think like a Computer Scientist",
        url="http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/")

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
        title="Learn Python in 10 Minutes",
        url="http://www.korokithakis.net/tutorials/python/")

    django_cat = add_cat("Django")

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="Official Django Tutorial",
        url="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/")

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="Django Rocks",
        url="http://www.djangorocks.com/")

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="How to Tango with Django",
        url="http://www.tangowithdjango.com/")

    frame_cat = add_cat("Other Frameworks")

    add_page(cat=frame_cat,
        title="Bottle",
        url="http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/")

    add_page(cat=frame_cat,
        title="Flask",
        url="http://flask.pocoo.org")

    # Print out what we have added to the user.
    for c in Category.objects.all():
        for p in Page.objects.filter(category=c):
            print ("- {0} - {1}".format(str(c), str(p)))

def add_page(cat, title, url, views=0):
    p = Page.objects.get_or_create(category=cat, title=title, url=url, views=views)[0]
    return p

def add_cat(name):
    c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
    return c

# Start execution here!
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("Starting Rango population script...")
    populate()
```

What is wrong with the code or is the fault is with another file ? Using python 3.4 and django 1.7. Have I missed a file ? is there an other file I should share?

[image: Page Objects]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem while studying through django with tango. I missed the method in the rango/modules.py in the class Page.

def **str**(self): # For Python 2, use **unicode** too
    return self.title

Answer (score 2):

`__unicode__(self)` seems to be creating the problem for Python-3 . Replace that with `__str__(self)` and it should work.

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Page(models.Model):
    category =  models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```